# Google Datastore backup restore to default database

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

I'm looking at the new [Backup and restore data](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/backups) functionality for Google Datastore (and Firestore), currently in Preview.

The [Restore data from a database backup](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/backups#restore_data_from_a_database_backup) part instructs on how to restore a backup **to a new** database:

```
gcloud alpha firestore databases restore \
    --source-backup=projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/backups/BACKUP_ID \
    --destination-database='DATABASE_ID'
```

`DATABASE_ID`: A database ID for the new database. **You cannot use a database ID that is already in use**. The database mode will match that of the backup.

What is the point in this? I understand these are intended (also) for Disaster Recovery:

> Use backups to protect your data from application-level data
> corruption or from accidental data deletion.

So in case my application suddenly gets his `(default)` database corrupted what am I supposed to do? Restore a backup in another database? Re-configure my application to use another database from `(default)` could take me more time.

Plus I cannot simply get rid of the corrupted `(default)` database deleting it because, I read:

> For the `(default)` database only, you must delete all related backups
> before you can delete the database.

[Exporting and Importing Entities](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities) exports to a Google Cloud Storage bucket you can re-import to the same database right after. So does [Point-in-time recovery](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/pitr), why scheduled backups do not?

I know I could restore to a different database, export to GCS and *then* import to `(default)`, time is critical in a Disaster Recovery it would be simpler having a direct option, is it available somewhere?

Comment: I think the docs are out of date about having to delete backups for the default database.  I'll follow up and have an answer later this week.

Answer (score 1):

This concern is already discussed [here](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Databases/Firebase-restore-from-backup-into-default/m-p/654929) and They mentioned that

> The Firebase backup feature is currently in Alpha, so the recovery process is not yet finalized.

However, you can try one of the approaches they mentioned, if it matches your requirement.

> Point your users to the new database instance. This would require you to push a new version of your app that uses the new database connection string. It would also mean that your users would no longer be able to take advantage of the free limits for the default database instance.

If you are not satisfied with this. You can raise ***feature request*** for the same in [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) by adding your concern.

Comment: Thanks, besides the costs increase, pointing to another database could mean more development than changing a connections string. BTW your link to public issue tracker is broken :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I have fixed the link.

Answer (score 1):

Your options to fix an issue in your default database from a backup are:

1. Restore to a new database, and use a tool like dataflow to repair the entities that need to be fixed.
2. Delete your default database (this does not require deleting backups anymore), then restore into the default database
3. Restore into a new database and point your clients to the new database.

Depending on what problem you are solving for (1 bad entity) vs I already deleted all my data vs I don't know what problem exists, you may pick any of the above solutions.

Comment: Thanks, the option to delete and restore the default database makes life easier. Still an option to export to Cloud Storage would streamline the recovery process with Point-in-time recovery, so to have one single process to follow if you have to recover data older vs newer than 7 days.

Comment: Are you asking to be able to be able to restore from an export?  Or do an export from anyttime in the PiTR window (supported)?

Comment: Hello @JimMorrison, since with PiTR I have the option to export the db to a GCS bucket `gcloud firestore export gs://bucket --snapshot-time=...` like I have with `gcloud datastore export gs://bucket`, I'm asking to be able to do the same also with [Backup and restore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/backups) so I do establish a unified recovery process, no matter where the backup comes from.

Comment: Sorry, it's still unclear what you are looking for.  What do you expect of the `gcloud firestore databases restore` command?

Comment: I would like to export a backup to a GCS bucket with e.g. `gcloud datastore|firestore export gs:/bucket --source-backup=...`